# How do I dynamically change an Android ListAdaptor elements style base on a condition, for example change the color

Tags: android, listadapter

'In the below android list adapter I wish to dynamically change the colour in the display of an element  based on a condition, for example if TAG_AMOUNT is greater than 2 then the text view is red.  Any help welcome!  (the below is based on androidhive JSON parsor)'

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
// dismiss the dialog after getting all products
pDialog.dismiss();
// updating UI from Background Thread
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    /**
    * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
    * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        AllProductsActivity.this,     productsList,
        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,TAG_NAME, TAG_AMOUNT, TAG_LOCATION},
       new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.amount, R.id.location});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** you can do this by Customizing SimpleAdapter class.

Here is [sample code](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/) for the same.

What you basically will be doing is overriding `getView` method of SimpleAdapter.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much for that, only just spotted the reply.  It works perfectly and taught me a few things I've been puzzling over. now to adapt it to exactly what I'm trying to do.   Appreciated!

Comment: The problem I have now in the SpecialAdapter shown in the link that CRUSADER posted is how you do a test on one of the elements in List<HashMap<String, String>>. In my case there are four categories, id, name, quantity and location, they are passed to List<HashMap<String, String>  by   productsList and productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); in the above example.   one of the categories is quantity and I wish to say something like:- if quantity != 1 then color the background or change the font for example.   very difficult to explain, so apologies if this is not clear.